# .effect('bounce') in jQuery is not working

Tags: jquery

I've got a little bit difficulty.

Why .effect doesn't work, but .fadeOut works just fine. It really confuses me to the bones. I can't move on to working if I don't solve this simple thing. Here is the html, css, and custom-script i make. Please help me, it will be very appreciated... :)

---

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styling.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="blue"></div>
<div class="button"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

### styling.css

```
.blue {width:400px; height:400px; background-color:blue; left:0px; position:absolute;}

.button {width:250px; height:150px; background-color:green; position: absolute; bottom:0px; left:0px; cursor: pointer;}
```

---

### script.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div.button').click(function(){$('div.blue').effect('bounce');});

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seem like you're missing jQuery UI files, you can add jQuery UI CSS and js reference files  to your code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Final included CSS and scripts order should look like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styling.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g2ajL/)**

Comment: I have another question, is bounce just viable for <div>. I attempted to change the <div> into <a> and it's no working. So, is it?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the jQuery-UI library:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

I've added it to your code and it is functioning now. Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5GKes/)

Comment: Thanks dude. It works!!! :D

and btw, is bounce just viable for <div>. I attempted to change the <div> into <a> and it's no working. Is it?